# How to send a JSON data to event push?

Tags: events, grails, groovy, websocket, push

I am using the events push plugin for grails.

Everything is working fine when I push simple data like this:

```
def mydata = [:]
mydata.message = "hello world"
event (topic: 'mySaved', data: mydata)
```

I can display this on my page like this:

```
grailsEvents.on('mySaved', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.message)
}
```

However, I want to send a whole instance to this topic and thats when it breaks.

So, for example:

```
def mydata = colorInstance as JSON
println mydata
event (topic: 'mySaved', data: mydata)
```

The above `println` prints this:

```
{"id":10,"color":"Red","description":"hot color"}
```

If I try to use it on my page like this:

```
grailsEvents.on('mySaved', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log("This is ID: " + data.id)
}
```

I don't get the desired result. The above prints the following in the console log:

```
Object {class: "grails.converters.JSON", depth: 0, writer: Object}
This is ID: undefined
```

**Question**

How can I send the `colorInstance` so that I can fetch it in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pushing

```
event( topic: 'mySaved', data: mydata.toString() )
```

Comment: That shows me `{"id":10,"color":"Red","description":"hot color"}` in the console because of `console.log(data)`. However, `console.log(data.id)` still shows undefined.

Comment: ah nevermind. I used `$.parseJson` to convert json string to JS object. Thanks!